# Unable to refer to Projection alias in Hibernate Restriction

Tags: java, hibernate

According to [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-projection), it says that

> An alias can be assigned to a projection so that the projected value can be referred to in restrictions or orderings.

However, I am somehow unable to refer to a projection alias in a restriction.

```
public List getRequests() {
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Request.class);
    crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("reward"), "pointsRewards"));
    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("pointsRewards"));
    crit.add(Restrictions.gt("pointsRewards", 0));
    return crit.list(); 
}
```

In the above code, while addOrder works, the adding of the restriction results in this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: pointsRewards of: entities.Request
```

Does anyone know how to refer to a projection alias in a restriction? I need to use a projection alias, as I will later require the result from Projections.sqlGroupProjection to restrict and narrow the criteria.

Thank you!